# Print success message in index page after posting data in php file

Tags: php, jquery, email

When I Enter Home Address and Email Id and click submit, the email sent successfully. But It doesn't show the success message in "div class = successbox"

What's wrong I am doing?

I have this index.html

```
<div class="w-container report">
<h2 class="reportheading"><br><br>Get Your Free On Demand<br>Comprehensive Home Valuation</h2>
<p class="reporttext">Receive current market trends; algorithms; neighborhood facts; comparable listing and sale prices; Sell Time!
  <br>
  <br>Your custom report is published and returned same day.</p>
<div class="w-form">
  <form name="myForm"  id="wf-form-Free-Report-2" action="process.php" name="wf-form-Free-Report" data-name="Free Report" method="post" class="reportform">
    <div class="w-clearfix formcenter">
      <input id="Home" type="text" placeholder="Enter Home Address, City &amp; Zip" name="Home" data-name="Home" required="required" class="w-input formbox spaceright">
      <input id="Email-2" type="email" placeholder="Enter Email Address" name="Email-2" data-name="Email" required="required" class="w-input formbox spaceleft">
    </div>
    <div class="btncenter">
      <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" data-wait="Please wait..." class="w-button formbutton">
    </div>
  </form>
  <div class="w-form-done succesbox">
    <p>Thank you!
      <br>Your Free report will be generated based on your physical address and will be emailed to you shortly.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="w-form-fail">
    <p>Excuse us but something went wrong when trying to submit the form.
      <br>Please try again.</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have process.php

```
<?php

$errors         = array();      // array to hold validation errors
$data           = array();      // array to pass back data

if (empty($_POST['name']))
    $errors['name'] = 'Name is required.';

if (empty($_POST['email']))
    $errors['email'] = 'Email is required.';

$to = "abc@xyz.com"; // this is your Email address
$from = $_POST['Email']; // this is the sender's Email address
$Home = $_POST['Home'];

$subject = "Request for Comprehensive Home Valuation";
$message = "House Address: ".$Home."<br/>Email Id: ".$from;

error_log("popat11 check this line", 0);    



if (mail($to,$subject,$message))
{

    $data['success'] = true;
    $data['message'] = 'Thank you!
                                  <br>Your Free report will be generated based on your physical address and will be emailed to you shortly.</p>';
}

// return all our data to an AJAX call

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Can you show your Ajax call with the success callback?

Comment: Might want to pull your email out of the code, too. ;)

Comment: I haven't used ajax call. I post all data from input to process.php using action. And i used those data to send message using mail() function. I newbie with jquery and ajax.

Comment: What's the point of checking for errors **AFTER** you've already sent the email? "let me just shoot myself into the foot, and then check if the gun was loaded".

Comment: Yes, i pulled out my email. thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is set up to be initiated by javascript (AJAX), and received/processed by javascript. Do you have supporting javascript code for this?

If you are not using javascript you could modify your code this way (a very simple example):

1. Rename index.html to index.php and then modify this portion:

```php
<div class="w-form-done succesbox">
  <?php if (!empty($_REQUEST['success'])) { ?>
    <p>Thank you!
      <br>Your Free report will be generated based on your physical address and will be emailed to you shortly.</p>
  <?php } else if (!empty($_REQUEST['error'])) ?>
    <p>Sorry! There was a problem./p>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

2. Modify your php file to say this in the lower portion:

```php
if ( ! empty($errors)) {
    header('Location:index.php?error=1');
} else {
   header('Location:index.php?success=1');
}   
// echo json_encode($data);  /* remove this line */
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to use ajax to do something (the process.php ) and then display an appropriate message on the original page.  You are missing your ajax call to process.php.

You could look at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ to see some sample ajax functions.

YOu want to do something like this after your ajax call to process.php

```
  $( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event,request, settings ) {
  $( "#msg" ).append( "<li>Request Complete.</li>" );
});
```

In your html, you don't have a msg id, but instead of the divs with the "pass" or "fail" content, you would display one of those messages like you have shown depending upon whether your returned data showed success or failure.

Hope this helps.